# HTTP 302 moved temporarily on spring security login with Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, http-status-code-302

I am using Grails with Spring Security without any customization.

The problem occurs only in production environment: 
When entering login information, I am redirected to the login screen with the HTTP code `302 moved temporarily`, but only the in the first try. All other attempts will be well succedded.

I tested several times using incognito tab, and absolutely always this happens.

I´m using Apache Tomcat 7, Grails 2.3.4 and Spring Security 2.0 RC2, totally default.

Comment: No, it was just a form with submit. I kind of resolved the problem by instead of redirect the user to myapp.com/login/auth to some url from the app, in my case myapp.com/dashboar/index. This way, when user click in login, actually I send him to the dashboard, and as he is not logged in, the sprin redirects him to the login page and then to the dashboard.
I really don´t know why this happens, but is solved for this caso.
Now I have problem with login facebook. When facebook redirect the user back to may app (https://myapp.com/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect) I am gettin the 302 again.